# Не получается прибиндить в коде

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Помогите пожалуйста доделать binding.

То что я уже сам сделал ...

```
canvas.RenderTransform = new TransformGroup { }.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform { ScaleX = ВОТ ТУТ КАК СДЕЛАТЬ?, ScaleY = ВОТ ТУТ КАК СДЕЛАТЬ?});

canvas.RenderTransform = new TransformGroup { }.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform { CameraX = ВОТ ТУТ КАК СДЕЛАТЬ?, CameraY = ВОТ ТУТ КАК СДЕЛАТЬ?});
```

Какой XAML должен получиться на выходе...

```
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Scale}" ScaleY="{Binding Scale}"/>
            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding CameraX}" Y="{Binding CameraY}"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
var st = new ScaleTransform();
BindingOperations.SetBinding(st, ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, new Binding("Scale"));
BindingOperations.SetBinding(st, ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, new Binding("Scale"));

var tt = new TranslateTransform();
BindingOperations.SetBinding(tt, TranslateTransform.XProperty, new Binding("CameraX"));
BindingOperations.SetBinding(tt, TranslateTransform.YProperty, new Binding("CameraY"));

canvas.RenderTransform = new TransformGroup()
{
    Children = new TransformCollection()
    {
        st,
        tt
    }
};
```

Comment: Идеально, спасибо Влад :)

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy: Пожалуйста!